# VLC Functionality: How to stream an .iso?

Tags: http, video, streaming, video-streaming, vlc

I gave a DVD ISO image and would like to use VLC's http function to create URL a user could access, after which the DVD would start up in full screen.

I can make this happen by accepting the defaults

vlc.exe -I http

navigating to localhost:8080 and then browsing and opening the file.  How would I modify this activity so that navigating to localhost:8080 instead opens a predetermined file and starts playing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do "-I http" this activates the http interface, not the streaming

if you want to stream the file, you usuallly do something like:

```
vlc -vvv input_stream --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=0.0.0.0:8080}'
```

this encodes and streams content from input_stream  to http port 8080

see [VLC streaming howto](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html#id517332) for more options.

hint : you can use the VLC GUI Wizard to find out your correct options.

Comment: in fact you dont really stream the iso to video. you stream the dvd contents to video.